# How to access a value from pandas column based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column column named url.

```
http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg
http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg'
http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg
```

I also have a column meta_data, it has two dictionary in a list.

```
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg' 'score': 54.09280014038086}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}]
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg' 'score': 99.902099609375}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}]
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg' 'score': 97.33160400390625}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg', 'score': 97.33160400390625}]"}]
```

I have a list with filenames in a variable.

```
file_names = ["41456gn7L.jpg","31mndfg.jpg","dsfsdf8587eh.jpg"]
```

I need to get the value of score (from the first dict in list) in the meta_data column, if the filename in url is on the file_names list.

How can I get it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': {0: 3234, 1: 3433, 2: 4443},
 'URL': {0: 'http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg',
  1: 'http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg',
  2: 'http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg'},
 'meta_data': {0: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg' 'score': 54.09280014038086}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}]",
  1: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg' 'score': 99.902099609375}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}]",
  2: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg' 'score': 97.33160400390625}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg', 'score': 97.33160400390625}]"}})
```

Comment: I would expand the metadata into a dataframe for easier filtering.

Comment: good idea, so it will be into a two columns right? But the key names are same in both dicts

Comment: The `meta_data` in your data is string, not *it has two dictionary in a list.*

Comment: Thanks, i will edit in the question

Answer (score 1):

From the example df you have provided, the values in meta_data seem like string. Assuming they are list of dictionaries as you mentioned in the question,

```
file_names = ["41456gn7L.jpg","31mndfg.jpg","dsfsdf8587eh.jpg"] 
df = pd.DataFrame({'url':['http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg','http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg','http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg'],
                'meta_data':[[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}],[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}],[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg' ,'score': 97.33160400390625}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg', 'score': 97.33160400390625}]]})
```

You can select the slice where the filename is present in list file_names and access value associated with the key 'score' from the `first element` of the list.

```
df['score'] = df.loc[df['url'].str.rsplit('/').str[-1].isin(file_names), 'meta_data'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['score'])

    url                                         meta_data         score
0   http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg     [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...   54.092800
1   http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg       [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...   99.902100
2   http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...   97.331604
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
metadata = [
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}, 
 {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}],
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg' ,'score': 99.902099609375}, 
 {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}],
[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg' ,'score': 97.33160400390625}, 
 {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg', 'score': 97.33160400390625}]
]
# Extract metadata into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([a[0] for a in metadata])

# List of filenames NOTE: added last file so match is found
fnList = ["41456gn7L.jpg","31mndfg.jpg","dsfsdf8587eh.jpg","31mnLrB5IHL.jpg"]

# show DF
print(df)
print("\n----\n Matching Filename\n")

# Generate list of matching scores
for f in fnList:
    try: v = df[df.imageUrl.str.contains(f)]['score'].iloc[0]
    except: v = None
    print(f, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'num': {0: 3234, 1: 3433, 2: 4443},
   ...:  'URL': {0: 'http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg',
   ...:   1: 'http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg',
   ...:   2: 'http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg'},
   ...:  'meta_data': {0: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg' 'score': 54.09280014038086}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://examp
   ...: le.com/images/41dY3ASVn7L.jpg', 'score': 54.09280014038086}]",
   ...:   1: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/31mnLrB5IHL.jpg' 'score': 99.902099609375}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/3
   ...: 1mnLrB5IHL.jpg', 'score': 99.902099609375}]",
   ...:   2: "[{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images/4189TDx0e0L.jpg' 'score': 97.33160400390625}, {'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/images
   ...: /4189TDx0e0L.jpg', 'score': 97.33160400390625}]"}})
   ...: file_names = ["41456gn7L.jpg","31mndfg.jpg","dsfsdf8587eh.jpg"]
   ...: df
Out[2]: 
    num                                         URL                                          meta_data
0  3234     http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...
1  3433       http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...
2  4443  http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...

In [3]: df['Score'] = df.loc[df.URL.apply(lambda x:x.split("/")[-1]).isin(file_names), :].meta_data.apply(lambda x:x.split(",")[-1]).str.extract(r"([\d]*[.][\
   ...: d]+)")

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    num                                         URL                                          meta_data              Score
0  3234     http://example.com/images/41456gn7L.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...  54.09280014038086
1  3433       http://example.com/images/31mndfg.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...    99.902099609375
2  4443  http://example.com/images/dsfsdf8587eh.jpg  [{'id': 0, 'imageUrl': 'http://example.com/ima...  97.33160400390625
```